# More efficient ways to initialize objects in java?

Tags: java, object, constructor

I have 10 objects here, but I have to intiliaze 20 more, is there a shorter way to do it?

```
            Gallina[] gallina=new Gallina[10];
        gato[0]=new Gato(true, "Siames", "Fluffy", 10);
        gato[1]=new Gato(false, "Persa", "Fluffy", 11);
        gato[2]=new Gato(true, "Maine Coon", "Fluffy", 9);
        gato[3]=new Gato(false, "Ragdoll", "Fluffy", 4);
        gato[4]=new Gato(false, "Bengala", "Fluffy", 1);
        gato[5]=new Gato(true, "Sphynx", "Fluffy", 6);
        gato[6]=new Gato(true, "Abisinio", "Fluffy", 3);
        gato[7]=new Gato(false, "Azulruso", "Fluffy", 9);
        gato[8]=new Gato(true, "Siberiano", "Fluffy", 2);
        gato[9]=new Gato(true, "Siames", "Fluffy", 4);
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the constructor.  public Gato(boolean garras, String raza, String nombre, int edad) {
  this.Garras = garras;
  this.Raza = raza;
  this.nombre = nombre;
  this.edad = edad;
 }

Comment: I would suggest using loops when it can be in any way parametrised. Also if you want to add some code to question - don't comment - edit it.

Comment: Seems like your are hardcoding a database into your application. Why not store the definitions in a file or an actual database?

Comment: Absolutely as @BoristheSpider says, get this data out of your code. :) Then stream it in. If you need help with that let us know.

Comment: You made an array of chickens, yet you populate an array of cats. I assume the types of array and its elements actually match in your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Gallina {
    private int gatoIndex = 0;

    private Gato[] gatos;

    public Gallina(int gatosLength) {
        gatos = new Gato[gatosLength];
    }

    public void addGato(boolean state, String name, String type, int value) {
        if (gatoIndex > gatos.length) {
            // an exception probably or resize array
        }
        gatos[gatoIndex] = new Gato(state, name, type, value);
        gatoIndex += 1;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gallina gallina = new Gallina(10);

        gallina.addGato(true, "ABC", "Fluffy", 10);
    }
}
```

Using a `List<Gato>` instead of `Gato[]` will help you get rid of `gatoIndex` and resizing the array yourself.

Basically with the above, you won't need to write the same `new Gato()` boilerplate everytime.

Answer (score 5):

You can avoid all the assignments, but I'm afraid it's not going to be much shorter:

```
Gato[] gato = new Gato[] {
    new Gato(true, "Siames", "Fluffy", 10),
    new Gato(false, "Persa", "Fluffy", 11),
    ...
};
```

This has two slight advantages over your technique:

- You cannot skip and/or overwrite an item by mixing up your indexes, and
- Java compiler will size your array according to the number of items that you put in it.

Obviously, this assumes that the array gets fully populated during initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using static factory methods instead of constructors.

It gives you some advantages:

- Static factory methods have names
- Static factory methods are not required to create a new object each time they're invoked
- Static factory methods can return an object of any subtype of their return
  type

Implementation

```
class Gato {
    private boolean field1;
    private String field2;
    private String field3;
    private int field4;


private Gato (boolean field1, String field2, String field3, int field4) {
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
    this.field3 = field3;
    this.field4 = field4;
}

public static Gato newInstance (boolean field1, String field2, String field3, int field4) {
    return new Gato(field1, field2, field3, field4);
}
```

So in your method you will use that implementation

```
gato[0] = Gato.newInstance(true, "Siames", "Fluffy", 10);
```

Comment: Although if the strict goal is "_shorter_" (less code) then this is the exact opposite...